# Установить позицию DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Сегодня обновил Chrome до последней версии, открыл DevTools (ПКМ - Просмотреть код), но внезапно он открылся в новом окне. (Скрин: [Тык](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbz9p.jpg))

Что ж, подумал я, и попытался найти кнопку для перемещения DevTools в нижнюю часть окна браузера (как это сделано в firefox: [Тык для просмотра скрина](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DmWO.jpg))

В предыдущих версиях хрома это можно было сделать в меню в правом верхнем углу, но открыв эту менюшку, кнопок для изменения позиции не оказалось: (Скрин: [Тык](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YgVP.jpg), а должно быть так: [Тык](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9x6a.jpg))

Вопрос: Куда делись эти кнопки? И как мне изменить позицию DevTools?

Comment: Chromium 69 — всё по-старому. Chrome стал отличаться от Chromium, что ли?

Comment: @andreymal даже не знаю, но как вы видите, на скрине, таких кнопок нет. Уже даже в меню settings смотрел, там тоже ничего не нашел(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте горячии клавиши в консоли `CTRL + SHIFT + D`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]